# Touch scroll on mobile - input issue

Tags: html, css, input, safari, touch

I have an issue with text inputs on mobile (responsive) site.

I am using next line on css:

```
body { -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch ; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

It's work good, except on inputs. when I fill the form with some text inputs - I can't see the values when I text it, it shows only after scrolling the page or moving to next field (tested on Safari).

i tried to fix it by adding:

```
input[type="text"] {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: none !important;
}
```

But - it didn't fix the issue.

I am using gamby framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just removed next line that I found on CSS file

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

I am not sure why this cause the bug, but it works now.